# Gnuplot: interactive SVG graph embedded on website shows wrong mouse coordinates when scaled

Tags: javascript, svg, gnuplot

When you embed a Gnuplot svg plot that was compiled with
set term svg size 600,480 mouse jsdir http://your.server.com/gnuplot-js-directory/
on your websize, you can toggle a coordinate box that shows the X and Y values.

If your SVG file is scaled in the `<embed>` or `<object>` tag relative to the size (600px by 480px) though, the coordinates are off and shown not next to the cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the gnuplot_svg.js in your gnuplot-js-directory.

Find the part where it says

```
p.x = evt.clientX; p.y = evt.clientY;
p = p.matrixTransform(m.inverse());

// Allow for scrollbar position (Firefox, others?)
if (typeof evt.pageX != 'undefined') {
    p.x = evt.pageX; p.y = evt.pageY;
}
```

and add the following lines:

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
                p.x = p.x / document.documentElement.clientWidth * gnuplot_svg.plot_term_xmax;
                p.y = p.y / document.documentElement.clientHeight * gnuplot_svg.plot_term_ymax;
        } else if (window.innerWidth) {
                p.x = p.x / window.innerWidth * gnuplot_svg.plot_term_xmax;
                p.y = p.y / window.innerHeight * gnuplot_svg.plot_term_ymax;
        }
```

The coordinate box position should now be scaled relative to the actual size of the SVG inside your  or  tag and will follow your cursor. (Works with Chrome and InternetExplorer, Firefox does not report the document.documentElement.clientWidth but window.innerWidth and the result should be the same. Have not tested Safari yet.)